# Windows 10 Sandbox custom configuration for Memory Size increase

Tags: windows-sandbox

I want to set memory size in Windows 10 Sandbox configuration file. Already I set required change in the configuration file but not working. I have followed this `<MemoryInMB>value</MemoryInMB>` command from Microsoft Windows sandbox configuration, but it's not working. Below is my Windows Sandbox configuration script:

```
<Configuration>
<VGpu>Disable</VGpu>
<Networking>Default</Networking>
<MemoryInMB>10240</MemoryInMB>
</Configuration>
```

Here VGpu and Networking are working properly, but the memory size has not changed.

Answer (score 2):

MemoryInMB is a new feature, introduced with Windows 10 build 2004:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-2004

Older versions of Windows will just ignore this tag.

Comment: fub68 thanks for your answer. I have solved this problem by windows updating in win 10 version 2004. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with the minimum. If I am not mistaken the minimum is 2GB. Try setting it up for more than 1024MB, e.g. 8192MB (8GB)

Comment: If I am reading the question correctly, the OP already has 10240MB = 10GB.

Comment: - rtoijala you are right. I had defined 10 GB not 1GB